# GetRequestStream() throws an exception

Tags: c#

I'm trying to upload a text file to an FTP server.

Here's the code:

```
public void upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
{
    try
    {
        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(" ftp://Gamification.somee.com/test.txt");

        //ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* When in doubt, use these options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = false;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        /* Open a File Stream to Read the File for Upload */
        FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Open);
        /* Buffer for the Downloaded Data */
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        /* Upload the File by Sending the Buffered Data Until the Transfer is Complete */
        try
        {
            while (bytesSent != 0)
            {
                ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                MessageBox.Show("succeded");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        localFileStream.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    return;
}
```

but the function throws an exception when it's running this line

```
ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
```

I think there's something wrong in the URL and maybe it's related to IP but I can't solve it.

Comment: What's the exception that it throws?

Comment: Put a breakpoint and inspect the exception and its inner exception.

Comment: Could it be that you've got a space in front of the uri? `WebRequest.Create(" ftp://Gamification.somee.com/test.txt");` - remove the space before `ftp`.

Comment: I tried to remove the space , and I still have the same exception .... I got this exception messege "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to get the details why its failing. until or unless you access the StatusDescription property's value.

```
catch(WebException ex)
{
    string message = ((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusDescription;
}
```

And let us know whats the message says.so that we can try to resolve this issue.I was not able to comment on this, hence added it as answer.

Please refer this answer of mine for Change Working Directory Scenarios. You will get a detail explanation here.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32724574/4553745

Comment: I got this message "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."

Comment: Please refer to the above link in the answer, Actually FtpWebRequest prevents to use CWD commands. so to enable that we need few lines of code to be added. Let me know if you still having some issue.

Comment: Call **SetMethodRequiresCWD()** before you call your **upload** Function .